# How to convert RGB{N0f8} type to Array{Float64}

Tags: arrays, image, image-processing, type-conversion, julia

I am trying to port the basic neural network application from Andrew Ng's course from Python to Julia but got stuck in this part.

I am using my own data set, and therefore I am creating my own solution to process images and resize them. In order to have the exact same as in the Python code (and to have all images as vectors inside one matrix) I need to convert them from RGB to Array type so I can store them as columns in a matrix, but I keep an error and I can't seem to find information anywhere else.

I'm currently using an adapted version of the idea presented [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/efficiently-loading-and-processing-large-number-of-images/58278/5?u=williantleite).

```
using Images, FileIO, TestImages

cat_path = "path/Cat/"
cat_imgs = joinpath.(cat_path, readdir(cat_path))

function process_image(path_vec::Vector{String}, h::Int64, w::Int64, label::Int64)
  result = zeros((h*w), length(path_vec))
  class = []
  for i in enumerate(path_vec)
    img = load(i[2])::Array{RGB{N0f8},2}
    img = imresize(img,(h,w))::Array{RGB{N0f8},2}
    img = vec(img)::Vector{RGB{N0f8}}
    result[:,i[1]] = img # this is the line where I believe Im getting the error
    push!(class, label) 
  end
  return result, class
end
```

If I try to change the images from RGB to Gray it works (which makes sense as they will have just one channel and will easily become an array), but if I want to keep all channels in the vector I can't just use save them into the matrix as a Vector{RGB{N0f8}}, and if I try to use `img = convert(Array{Float64,1},img)` I get the error: `MethodError: Cannot` convert `an object of type RGB{N0f8} to an object of type Float64`

I'm not sure how to make the code easily reproducible, but I believe that if you create a folder with a single image and update the file paths it should be possible. Or just running the individual lines inside the function using a test image:

```
using TestImages
img = testimage("mandrill")
```

Comment: To convert pixel to a number, a way to convert color to float needs to be specified. Colors have a lot of intricacies (ins and outs as the Big L says). The simplest way seems to me: `Float64.(Gray.(img))`

Comment: Yeah, with Gray.(img) it works, but then I lose information. I am trying to find a way to keep all of the information in still.

Comment: Perhaps you can extract 3 arrays for each color channel (R,G,B). For example for the Red channel use: `Float64.(red.(img))`

Comment: Good idea! Will try to find a way to implement it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. As I mentioned earlier, there is more to pixel colors than simple R,G,B. If these matrices are inputs to further machine learning processing, you might want to consider other color spaces (and look what other workflows openly available on the internet are doing).

Comment: Yeah, I gave a quick look in the documentation but couldn't laser point what to use, gotta put some more time into it. I wish it would be possible to just dot product the RGB types with floats (as that would save a lot of time and trouble I think), but I couldn't find a quick solution for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `channelview`. Note that RGB values will be available as the first dimension.

```
julia> channelview(testimage("mandrill"))
3×512×512 reinterpret(reshape, N0f8, ::Array{RGB{N0f8},2}) with eltype N0f8:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.643  0.471  0.388  …  0.475  0.494  0.035
 0.588  0.49   0.29      0.58   0.663  0.043
 0.278  0.243  0.122     0.608  0.659  0.047

;;; …

[:, :, 512] =
 0.702  0.471  0.376  …  0.318  0.314  0.016
 0.737  0.541  0.314     0.314  0.247  0.02
 0.463  0.29   0.192     0.235  0.278  0.008
```

If you want to have a different layout of dimensions you could use `permutedims` together with `channelview`:

```
julia> permutedims(channelview(testimage("mandrill")),[2,3,1])
512×512×3 Array{N0f8,3} with eltype N0f8:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.643  0.247  0.294  0.373  0.616  …  0.275  0.569  0.459  0.553  0.702
 0.471  0.529  0.216  0.294  0.455     0.51   0.478  0.478  0.533  0.471
 ⋮                                  ⋱                       ⋮
```

Comment: I looked into it, but my problem is that I didnt manage to flatten the channelview afterwards. The idea is to have each image vector (with all channels) as a column in a matrix.

Comment: use `permutedims` - see my edit. Or `reshape` if you want a different shape of the data

Comment: Just tested your suggestion now and it works wonders without having to resort to a for loop. The specific solution applying what you said looks like `x = reshape(channelview(imresize(testimage("mandrill"), (32,32))), (3072, 1)) `  now I just need to plug it into the function. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

After Dan's suggestion I managed to find a solution, although probably a slow/inefficient one:

```
function process_image(path_vec::Vector{String}, h::Int64, w::Int64, label::Int64)
  result = zeros((h*w*3), length(path_vec))
  class = []
  for i in enumerate(path_vec)
    img = load(i[2])::Array{RGB{N0f8},2}
    img = imresize(img,(h,w))::Array{RGB{N0f8},2}
    img = vec(img)::Vector{RGB{N0f8}}
    img = [temp(img[i]) for i = 1:length(img), temp in [red, green, blue]]
    img = reshape(img, ((h*w*3),1))
    result[:,i[1]] = img
    push!(class, label) 
  end
  return result, class
end
```

In case it isn't clear in the code, what I did was extracting 3 arrays for each color channel into a matrix, which produces a 1024x3 Array{N0f8,2}. Then you can reshape this array into a 3072x1 Array{N0f8,2}. Once reshaped you can add it to a zeros matrix and it converts to Array{Float64,2}.

Not super happy that I had to manually input the number of channels to get the right dimension, but it works.

Comment: Julia usually doesn't require any type specifiers unless explicitly converting/casting. So all the `::Array{RGB{N0f8},2}` and the like can be removed with no harm (even benefit).

Comment: I see, main reason why I added them was because I heard it could speed up the process. Im looping over quite a lot of images, so I'm trying to get this code bit running as fast as possible.

Comment: It will not speed up anything, it's just visual noise.

Comment: If I change `[red, green, blue]` (array) to `(red, green, blue)` (tuple), that line speeds up >200x for me. Also, what is the purpose of repeatedly pushing the same label to the `class` vector (which should be initialized as `Int[]`, btw.)

Comment: hmm, will try changing the tuple thing to see if it speeds up for me. The whole loop is taking around 4min for me for about 25000 (800mb) images. The push was an underdeveloped idea hehe, my plan was to do a general loop for both folders (the data has a folder per class), but then I never really implemented it. In this case I can just take out the push and use zeros or ones for that variable I think.

Comment: I think it is likely that most of the time is spent loading the images.

Comment: Yes, I think so too, even after changing to tuple it still stays at 4min, which is similar to the time it takes in python, and much faster than in R. The push!() I had to keep because it triggers only when there's no exception. I had to add a couple of try/catch statements cause of some annoying dimensions and types in some of the images.